# “They got nice cars” correct or not?

Tags: grammaticality

> Yeah, some of them always got the nicest cars.

Is this correct? “Got” doesn’t sound right to me, I would’ve said they have the nicest cars but does the above sentence still have correct grammar?

Comment: This will be closed since right/wrong answers are not usually acceptable. But bear this in mind: English has two forms for have in the present simple: have and have got. Just using "got" is either non-standard for have or can mean "buy". But given the "Yeah", this is most likely non-standard for have got or have. Please go read the Help section. Top right under the three-bars icon.

Comment: *Got* is correct here if it is used in the sense of *acquired*.

Comment: That sentence is perfectly idiomatic but very colloquial American English. One step in the direction of formality, but still colloquial, would be *They've got nice cars* and yet another step towards formal, but still in neutral register, would be *They have nice cars*.  It is also possible to understand the sentence as a statement about the past, where "got" means "acquired".

Comment: If meant for 'Yes, some of them always have the nicest cars', it's quite possibly AAVE.

Comment: Got can mean: bought, purchased, acquired and received to name a few. However, I repeat the presence of "yeah" points to the non-standard got for have/have got. It is idiomatic but non-standard and mostly unschooled. It is not AAVE per se. It's any American uneducated dialect.

Comment: Oh, yes, ask a question and then delete a profile. Why bother? I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yeah, they always got nice cars. [past tense of have got/ have, non-standard]
2. They always got nice cars. [**could also be**: bought or acquired or received, past tense of have got/get]
3. They'**ve always got** nice cars. [in their garage, for example]
4. They **always have** nice cars. [in their garage or whatever]   3) and 4) mean the same thing and are standard.

Unless *got* in 1) means something other than have/have got, like bought or received, it would be standard American English. The only discourse level indicator is the "yeah". So, I'm reading it as have got/have, and therefore non-standard. **But it can be read otherwise, as received or bought**.

*Yeah, he got some nice shoes at the mall. [bought, standard]

The question forms for that non-standard form would be:
*Do you got a nice car? [for have/have got]
*Don't you got a nice car [for have/have got?

*Did you get a nice car? [standard, buy]